# UIHint can not resolve template in abstract models

Tags: c#, resharper, abstract-class, mvc-editor-templates, asp.net-mvc-uihint

Assume an abstract model like this:

```
 public abstract class MyClass : BaseEntity
{
    [UIHint("File")]
    public long? DocumentFileId { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is `Cannot resolve template 'File'`, while there is File.cshtml in View editor templates.

[image: Message as shown in Visual Studio]

The point is, if I don't define MyClass as an abstract class, error will be solved.

My question is, why editor template can not resolve in abstract classes, and how can I handle it?

Comment: Where are the templates stored? MVC will only find them if they are in  a folder called `EditorTemplates` or `DisplayTemplates` which is in `Views/Shared/` or `Views/{YourController}`.

Comment: @DavidG: Right, and mine is there. This template is working all over the project but abstract classes.

Comment: Where are you getting the error?

Comment: Follow up question, are you using ReSharper?

Comment: yes, I'm using ReSharper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug with ReSharper that was [reported](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-373171) almost a year ago. Doesn't look like JetBrains are in a rush to fix it.

However, it shouldn't interfere with your development other than being a nuisance.

Comment: I changed the severity from Error to Suggestion to get rid of the eye catching red color

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to suppress the warning at the class level, like this;

```
[SuppressMessage("ReSharper", "Mvc.TemplateNotResolved")]
public abstract class MyClass : BaseEntity
{
    // ....
```

Answer (score 0):

I disabled this warning in abstract classes with comments.

```
// Resharper 8 fails to resolve templates in abstract classes.
// https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-373171
// ReSharper disable Mvc.TemplateNotResolved
public abstract class MyAbstractClass
{
    ...
```